# Equals and HashCode execution flow

Tags: java

I am bit confused about when exactly HashCode and equals method gets called.
for e.g.

- If map.put(1, "One") called first time.
- If map.put(1, "Two") called second time.

Answer (score 4):

hashCode() is always called. This is needed to find the bucket to place the entry in.

equals() is called if there is a key in the same bucket, e.g. if the key is the same. However, some hash maps might not call equals if it is exactly the same object, as it is in your example.

Note: if your map is a sorted map such as TreeMap, neither hashCode nor equals is called. TreeMap and ConcurrentSkipListMap use the compareTo method or a provided `Comparable` to determine where the key is placed in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

hashcode() is a function that generate a unique code to find bucket(its just like index in array). while if you want to make different definition of your object equality then you can override equals().

Comment: Note: While `hashCode` is unique for `Integer` is not guarenteed to be unique for other types like `String`

Comment: @PeterLawrey true that for string hashcode may not unique that's why every character is involved for doing math with prime number.